# Fragment null must be a public static class to be properly recreated from instance state

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragment, android-sdk

Есть проект на Android, на старых версиях все работает хорошо, вот сейчас пробую собрать под API26 и, когда пытаюсь вызвать DatePicker, то получаю следующую ошибку.

```
    Process: com.dcorp.app.taskcheck, PID: 1913
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment null must be a public static class to be  properly recreated from instance state.
    at android.app.BackStackRecord.doAddOp(BackStackRecord.java:429)
    at android.app.BackStackRecord.add(BackStackRecord.java:409)
    at android.app.DialogFragment.show(DialogFragment.java:229)
    at com.dcorp.app.taskcheck.dialog.AddingTaskDialogFragment$3.onClick(AddingTaskDialogFragment.java:138)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6256)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24697)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Код DatePickerFragment

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
    implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {


@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), (DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener) getParentFragment(), year, month, day);
}

@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

}
```

}

и

```
etDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (etDate.length() == 0) {
                etDate.setText(" ");
            }

            DialogFragment datePickerFragment = new DatePickerFragment() {
                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                    calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
                    calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
                    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
                    etDate.setText(Utils.getDate(calendar.getTimeInMillis()));
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                    etDate.setText(null);
                }
            };
            datePickerFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "DatePickerFragment");


        }
    });
```

Я как понимаю ошибка получается при попытке вывести датапикер. Как можно решить данную проблему? Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Если класс DatePickerFragment вложенный, то его надо объявить `static`, либо сделать данный класс верхнего уровня (и без `static`). Кроме того, можно попробовать объявить переменную фрагмента так `final DialogFragment datePickerFragment = ...`.

Comment: Так у меня  DialogFragment класс верхнего уровня, в вопросе есть код этого класса.

Comment: final попробовали?

Comment: да, всё та же ошибка

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы неправильно используете `DialogFragment`. В вашей ситуации проще всего его не использовать вообще. Исправить это проще всего вот так :

```
public class DatePickerController implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {


    public Dialog createDialog(Context context) {

        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        return new DatePickerDialog(context, this, year, month, day);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

    }
}
```

И используйте eго следующим образом :

```
new DatePickerController().createDialog(activity).show();
```

P.S. Если хотите использовать именно `DialogFragment` нужно переопределять не `onCreateDialog`, а `onCreateView`. И при этом реализовывать логику пикера.
Если же вы хотите использовать `DatePickerDialog` - то это **готовый** диалог используйте его как есть, и его ненужно оборачивать в DialogFragment.

Comment: Супер заработало! Большое Вам спасибо!